# Make the function comparing two variables with different value print True

Tags: programming-puzzle, c#

Without changing the actual function, call it in such a way that it prints "True"

```
void Puzzle(out int x, out int y)
{
  x = 0;
  y = 1;
  Console.WriteLine(x == y);
}
```

[Online Tester](http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=9663)

Comment: Programming puzzle challenges should usually include some indication how the "best" answer is chosen is several valid solutions are posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reusing reference:

```
//C# Puzzle: Call the Puzzle() function in Main such that it prints True. 
//You have to do this without changing the Puzzle method.

public void Main()
{
  int x,y;
  Puzzle(out x, out x);
}

void Puzzle(out int x, out int y)
{
    x = 0;
    y = 1;
    Console.WriteLine (x == y);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved!

```
Puzzle(out x, out x);
```

http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=9697